# Where can I find this accordion jQuery plugin?

Tags: jquery

A long time ago I have seen a plugin I think it is Accordion plugin
its like that

```
item 1 >>> item4
```

it merge it in one item and when hover by mouse its will be

```
item 1 > item 2 > item 3 > item4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

jBreadCrumb

http://www.comparenetworks.com/developers/jqueryplugins/jbreadcrumb.html

Comment: oh my god oh my god this is the exactly iam looking for i cant belive